# Query mailbox or let exchange push a message to my script?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, exchange-server, exchangewebservices

I have a list of actions happened on an item listed on an ASP.net website. These actions are logged in a simple sql table linked to the item.
i.e.:

```
[2013-11-04 18:00]: Problem solved
[2013-11-04 18:00]: Called User
[2013-11-04 14:00]: Mail Received
```

For this, I will have to query the support mailbox for new mail messages. When a new message is received, a 'mail received' action is created. The 'mail received' entry should be clickable so the support user can see the contents of this message.

Question: **How do I query this mailbox?**

Do I need to create a scheduled task and use Exchange Webservices Managed API 2.0 to query this mailbox every 5 minutes?

Or can I set-up exchange to 'push' this message to my script? If so.. how?

We are using an on-premise Exchange 2010 SP3 server that should be migrated to Exchange Online some time next year. Application is running on ASP.NET 4.5 using MVC 5.0 framework.

Answer (score 1):

The EWS Managed API supports a number of ways to do this:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh312849(v=exchg.140).aspx

You can set up pull notifications (simple polling), push notifications (must set up a contract on both ends), streaming notifications (kind of the best of both worlds), or set up a periodic sync of the inbox. Once you have that much working, it's just a matter of moving the data around to trigger events. The sync action is not mentioned in the article, but can be invoked via the ExchangeService object.

Comment: Thank you. So a streaming notification is just like a push notification but with the connection kept open for 30 minutes? Does someone have a complete examples on how to set up a service & how to prepare a subscription on exchange?